# Optional query string parameters in ASP.NET Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

In my advanced search form I have around 25 fields. When I submit the form all parameters are passed to the URL even when null. How may I pass the parameters which have only been changed by the user and have a value? All 25 fields are optional.

I have around 25 of these:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
[Display(Name = "Foo")]
public int? Foo{ get; set; }
```

OnGetAsync:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
   Properties = await _DarkMatterRepo.FindAsync(Foo, ...)
   return Page(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How may I pass the parameters which have only been changed by the user and have a value?

To achieve the above the requirement, you can try to check form data and navigate to expected page, like below.

Code of form

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="emailaddress">
    <input type="number" name="age">
    @*other input fields*@
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Dynamically generate QueryString and navigate to specific page

```
<script>
    $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //console.log($(this).serializeArray());
        var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();
        var parm = "";
        $.each(formdata, function (index, item) {
            if (item.value!="") {
                parm += item.name + "=" + item.value + "&";
            }
        });

        //console.log(parm.substring(0, parm.length - 1));

        window.location.href = "@Url.Page("Index")" + "?" + parm.substring(0, parm.length - 1);
    });
</script>
```